# Retrofit Post Parameter

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I am implementing login feature and for that using Post request but i am getting error saying

> "retrofit.RetrofitError:
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpMethod.METHODS"

Below is my code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.*;




//Myapi.java

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.*;

public interface MyApi {

    /* LOGIN */
    @POST("/api/0.01/oauth2/access_token/")
    // your login function in your api
    public void login(@Body HashMap<String, String> arguments, Callback<String> calback);
}


//In my activity
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Constants_Interface.URL).setClient(newclient)
                .build();

        MyApi mylogin = restAdapter.create(MyApi.class); 
HashMap<String, String> dicMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
dicMap.put("client_id", XXX);
        dicMap.put("client_secret", XXX);
        dicMap.put("username", XXX);
        dicMap.put("password", XXX);
mylogin.login(dicMap, new Callback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                retrofitError.printStackTrace(); // to see if you have
                                                    // errors
            }

            @Override
            public void success(String s, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Succes",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Below it logcat output.

> 02-10 13:02:43.846: W/System.err(30684): retrofit.RetrofitError:
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpMethod.METHODS 02-10

Comment: If you're server is expecting Json then try making the @Body argument a class.

Comment: No it is not expecting json object. It is asking parameter as string only.

Comment: Retrofit serializes your @Body class by default so Im sure your server will be getting a string

Comment: I have updated the logcat output can you please look over it?

Comment: Thats quite easy make a LoginResponse class with the fields expected from the server and use Callback<LoginResonse> rather than Callback<String>, Retrofit is trying to deserialize.

Comment: I tried @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("/api/0.01/oauth2/access_token/")
 // your login function in your api
 public void login(@Field("client_id") String client_id,
   @Field("client_secret") String client_secret,
   @Field("username") String username,
   @Field("password") String password, Callback<String> calback);

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try using this

```
public interface SafeUserApi {
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/userlogin")
    void getUserLogin(
            @Field("client_id") String id,
            @Field("client_secret") String secret,
            @Field("username") String uname,
            @Field("password") String password,
            Callback<LoginResult> cb
    );
}
```

Here parm1 is the POST parameter that you will be passing it to the server.
This will solve your problem

in case if you are using PHP u can access the param1 using `$uname= $_POST('username');`

**EDIT 1:**

retrofit 2.0 version:

```
public interface SafeUserApi {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/userlogin")
    Call<ResponseBody>  getUserLogin(
            @Field("client_id") String id,
            @Field("client_secret") String secret,
            @Field("username") String uname,
            @Field("password") String password
    );
}
```

Comment: can u paste the stack trace in pastebin ans share the link here?

Comment: What is I want to use application/json MIME type?  Should I still use @FormUrlEncoded

Comment: if u remove the callbacks then how will u respond to the response

Comment: I also can not access the parameters by using $_POST['username'] in my PHP code.

Comment: are u sure u used the same `@FormUrlEncoded` and `@Field` ?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183506/how-to-use-wcf-services-in-android-using-retrofit

Comment: if u remove the callbacks then how will u respond to the response

Answer (score 8):

**You can also pass multiple field parameter:**
for example:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/oauth/access_token")
void getToken(
    @FieldMap Map<String, String> params, 
    Callback<FacebookLoginUserResponse> callback
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Retrofit 2.0 version:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/v2/users/sign_in")
Call<SignInResult> userSignIn(
        @FieldMap HashMap<String, String> authData
);
```

Answer (score 3):

"JSON CONVERSION

**Retrofit uses Gson by default to convert HTTP bodies to and from JSON.** If you want to specify behavior that is different from Gson's defaults (e.g. naming policies, date formats, custom types), provide a new Gson instance with your desired behavior when building a RestAdapter. Refer to the Gson documentation for more details on customization."

See link for more info:
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I already tried with field parameter as well. @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("/api/0.01/oauth/access_token/")
 // your login function in your api
 public void login(@Field("client_id") String client_id,
   @Field("client_secret") String client_secret,
   @Field("username") String username,
   @Field("password") String password, Callback<String> calback);

Answer (score 3):

I got this error today

> ("retrofit.RetrofitError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpMethod.METHODS")

The problem was I was using different versions okhttp and okhttp-urlconnection, so make sure they match.

Comment: Thank you! This saved my life, thought I was going to have to upgrade to Retrofit 2. I was getting an error like  retrofit.RetrofitError: No field METHODS, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the class like this:

```
public interface SafeUserApi {
    @POST("/api/userlogin")
    void getUserLogin(@Body PostData postData);
}

public class PostData{
      String client_id;
      String client_secret;
      String username;
      String password;
}
```