# Retrofit2: Sending POST request with String request

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hi I am new to android and now I am using Retrofit for integrating the web services.

I am not understanding how to send parameters to the server using Retrofit POST request.

Please help me. Thanks.

### MainActivity:-

```
 String url = "XXXXXXXXX/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        PostInterface service = retrofit.create(PostInterface.class);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("email", "device3@gmail.com");
            jsonObject.put("password", "1234");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String result = jsonObject.toString();

        service.getStringScalar(result).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                System.out.println("result is====>" + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Failuere");
            }
        });
    }
```

### PostInterface:-

```
public interface PostInterface {

    @POST("User/DoctorLogin")
    Call<String> getStringScalar(@Body String body);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit Post Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426154/retrofit-post-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new model class :

```
public class Credentials {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    public Credentials(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Then modify your interface :

```
public interface PostInterface {

    @POST("User/DoctorLogin")
    Call<String> getStringScalar(@Body Credentials body);
}
```

Then call it like this :

```
service.getStringScalar(new Credentials("device3@gmail.com", "1234")).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            System.out.println("result is====>" + response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Failuere");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok let me check and tell you result

Comment: No i am getting Failure response means onFailure calling

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface PostInterface {

@POST("User/DoctorLogin")
Call<JsonObject> getStringScalar(@Field("PARAMATER_ID") String body);}
```

You can use string also in place of jsonobject,but i would recomment using json. "@Field(YOUR_PARAMETER)" is the way you use this

Comment: what is this how can call this from my mainActivity?

Comment: u are using  Call<String> getStringScalar(@Body String body);   ...... correct is  Call<JsonObject> getStringScalar(@Field("PARAMATER_ID") String body);     ..... for setting parameter field is the key u use not body

Answer (score 0):

Read [this artical](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) this will help you to understand retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

create a model class

```
public class Model {

String userName;
String password;

}
```

generate getter and setter

modify your interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("User/DoctorLogin")
Call<Model> loadDetail(@Field("user_id") String user_id,
                       @Field("password") String password);
}
```

and call it like this

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(url)
            .build();

    ApiInterface service = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<Model> call = service.loadDetail("username", "password");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {

            int statusCode = response.code();
            Model user = response.body();

            Log.d("userName: "  user.getUserName());
           Log.d("password: " + user.getPassword());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```