# POST from Android to Ruby on Rails WebAPI with retrofit2

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a valid WebApi I have built via Ruby on Rails. I have entries in this WebAPI I am able to successfully list and access with a @GET request, but I am unable to POST new entries to the WebAPI from Android.

Furthermore, I am able to POST an entry to the WebAPI from an application called POSTMAN and when I try to call my createCourse method as defined in my WebApi interface, my WebApi logs show no evidence of the call being made.

The fact that the request apparently fails to send in the first place confuses me, but in either case I imagine the problem is how I'm calling my retrofit POST. I'm aware [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816733/retrofit2-sending-post-request-with-string-request) poster has a similar issue, but the structure of his project is different enough from mine I'm not sure how it applies.

In my WebApi interface, here are the working @GET and the dysfunctional @POST

```
//CREATE
    @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @POST("/courses/create/")
    Call<Course> createCourse(@Body Course CourseName);
//LIST
@GET("/courses")
    Call<List<Course>> getCourses();
```

Also in my WebApi interface, I have the following

```
public static class Course {

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @SerializedName("name") private String name;
    @SerializedName("location") private String location;
    @SerializedName("startDate") private String startDate;
    @SerializedName("endDate") private String endDate;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
}
```

I have an App class that extends Application, and among unrelated things, it contains the following

```
public WebApi getWebApi() {
    if (webApi == null) {
        webApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("https://validurl.com") //i plug in something valid in implementation
                .build()
                .create(WebApi.class);
    }
    return webApi;
}
```

In the activity where I call the @GET request, it looks like this

```
Observable.just(getApi().getCourses())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(x -> {
                try {
                    return x.execute();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            })
            .map(x -> x.body())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(x -> {
                adapter.updateCourses(x);
            }, ex -> {
            });
```

in the activity where I call the @GET, I have defined

```
public WebApi getApi() {
    return ((App) getApplication()).getWebApi();
}
```

The "adapter" bit is irrelevant to my question as it pertains to my local database - it works fine!

Where I call the (nonworking) @POST, it looks like this

```
    WebApi.Course onlinecourse = new WebApi.Course();
    onlinecourse.setName(localcourse.name());
    onlinecourse.setLocation(localcourse.location());
    onlinecourse.setStartDate(localcourse.start_date());
    onlinecourse.setEndDate(localcourse.end_date());
```

after doing that, I use one of the following (neither work) to try and send the POST (to be fair, I should be using my elsewhere-defined getWebApi() method here instead of using the one native to the App class after casting, but the result is the same)

```
((App) getApplication()).getWebApi().createCourse(onlinecourse);
```

OR

```
    Observable.just(((App) getApplication()).getWebApi().createCourse(onlinecourse))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(x -> {
                try {
                    return x.execute();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            })
            .map(x -> x.body())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ;
```

I imagine this call is where things aren't working. Maybe I'm not understanding how retrofit works but I thought the way I have it sends the object as JSON. I'm not sure whether this is true, how I could check that, or why it seems no POST request is being sent to my API in the first place (it doesn't appear in the logs as the GET ones do)

Comment: Does your app crashes? Does the call throw an exception? I don't see the Retrofit.Builder().addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())

Comment: I'll try adding the addCallAdapterFactory line. As is, the app neither crashes or throws any visible exception...it acts as if the call is never made or the call is valid but it never gets to my WebApi.

Comment: I've imported  retrofit2.Retrofit and retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory and tried retrofit2.* but RxJavaCallAdapterFactory is not recognized

Comment: try to put this in your app gradle file: compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'. You can also try: 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1' to see what's going on in Retrofit (read documentation to see how to use the latter)

Comment: ill try this tonight when i can get back to it in around 3 hours. thanks.

Comment: All right so it's been a couple weeks since I toyed around with it, but I actually already had the logging interceptor implemented and I couldn't get it to actually print anything to the console. Also, I added the .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFa‌​ctory.create() bit after setting to compile the class and rebuilding Gradle. Still, nothing seems to happen. No errors are thrown, but I also have nothing in my WebAPI logs that imply a POST request was made. I'm at a loss.

Comment: That is because are not subscribing to the Observable. Observables até lazy, so If you dont subscribe, It will never be evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never subscribe to your Observable, so it is never going to be evaluated. Also, the way your created your WebApi interface is wrong, if you planing to use RxJava.

First, change your WebApi interface to this:

```
//CREATE 
    @Headers("Content-type: application/json") 
    @POST("/courses/create/") 
    Observable<Course> createCourse(@Body Course CourseName);
//LIST 
@GET("/courses") 
    Observable<List<Course>> getCourses();
```

So now, when you call getCourses you are going to get a Observable.

Second, call your methods like this:

```
  (App) getApplication()).getWebApi()
              .createCourse(onlinecourse))
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())          
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
              .subscribe(new Observer<Course>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    //Code here
                }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //Code here
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Course course) {
                    //Code here - Do something with course!

            }
```

This will your work.
Happy coding!

Comment: I don't know enough to explain why, but this doesn't work. After converting Call to Observable, the "x" I'm trying to use in `.map(x -> x.body())` acts like an object of the Course class instead of a retrofit2 response so I can't call retrofit2 methods like "body()" on. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to call ResponseBody.body(), or call "body()". Your Retrofit already parses the Json object for you using Gson. When the Retrofit returns it to you, it gives you a Course object. That's what you need right?? All you have to do is to deal with this object in the onNext(Course course) method. I don't think the you need the map function... so I removed it of my answer

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was just ignorant of what changes I should make because I hadn't initially planned to use RxJavaCallAdapterFactory. Thanks so much. For anyone who wants to refer to this in the future, know that `RespostaInsereImagem` is to be replaced with `WebApi.Course` in this answer. Cheers!

Comment: You are welcome! Sorry about that... it was a copy/paste from a code. It is fixed now!