# How to pass @POST parameter into retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

how to pass parameter to the @POST in the retrofit2

my interface service

```
public interface OdooService {

@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/xmlrpc/2/common")
fun getServerInfo(
        @Field("jsonrpc") jsonrpc: String,
        @Field("method") method: String,
        @Field("params")params:Any): Observable<Any>
```

i want to request payload look like this

{ jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "call",params: params}

Comment: params is AnyObject you need to pass String or something

Comment: Maybe it will help you:
[retrofit-post-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426154/retrofit-post-parameter)

Comment: how to check the body that being sent in the android studio?