# Not sure how to pass android data to php file to log in as a user to a sql database

Tags: php, android

I am not sure how to send login info from my code on android studio to my php file.

```
<?php   
require "conn.php";   
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];  
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];   
$mysql_qry = "select * from User_Login where User_Name like '$user_name' and User_Password like '$user_pass';";   
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);   
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {   
    echo "login successful!";   
}   
else {   
    echo "login unsuccessful";   
}   
?>
```

I have tried hard coding the username and password and it works. Yet, when I use `$_POST["user_name"];` and `$user_pass = $_POST["password"];`, it does not fill in the php variable with the information I passed from android.

Would anyone know how to do this? (How to make android fill in the php variable)

Comment: Hey dude. You should use some framework to access your API. For example if you are going to use Retrofit, you can follow this link to see how to send params through Android:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426154/retrofit-post-parameter

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually found out the problem was with my syntax in my java code. I spelled the password there as user_pass when it was supped to be just password.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some framework to access your API. For example if you are going to use Retrofit, you can follow this link to see how to send params through Android:
[Retrofit Post Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426154/retrofit-post-parameter)

And you may send the params with something like this:

```
public interface AuthApi {
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/conn.php")
    void doUserLogin(
            @Field("user_name") String username,
            @Field("password") String password,
            Callback<LoginResult> resultCallback
    );
}
```